# is_unique func of form validation in codeigniter is not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks

Currently I am using codeigniter 2.0.2 version. I have searched all files but not found declaration of is_unique function for form validation where I can check either username is already exists.

Should I create it my self, Is it best or download some other version ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`is_unique` was added, if I recall, in 2.1. So download that.

Comment: How is 2.0.2 higher than 2.1.0?

Comment: @Aryans No you're not. You're using 2.0.2. You need 2.1.0.

Comment: @Indranil: sorry misunderstanding :)

Comment: @KristianAntonsen: misunderstanding